# jQuery to display textbox based on value selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two tables one contain the numbers (Test) and it connected to the ID's of other table (Demo).

Test:
ID testing
1  1 
2  20

Demo:
ID Demoname
1  Maths
2  Physics

Now, I created a form for the entries. if the user selects Maths in the drop sown then a textbox has to be displayed otherwise it has to be hidden.

The below is my jquery and am unable to display the textbox even the user selects the Maths from the dropdown

```
function validate(){
var testing= document.getElementById("testing").value;
}

function subjectChange(){
        var value = $('#testing option:selected').text();
        if(value == "1"){
            $("#subShow").show();
        }else{
            $("#subShow").hide();
        }
    }


<tr>
    <td><span class="style2"><br> Subject: </span></td>
    <td><br>
    <select class="inputfield"  name="testing" id="testing" onchange="return subChange();">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <?php 
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sub_details)) {
                $select = @$adddetails['Testing'] == $row['ID'] ? "selected" : "";
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" <?php echo $select;?>><?php echo $row['Demoname']; ?></option>
            <?php   
            }
        ?>
    </select></td>
  </tr>


<?php 
  if($adddetails['Testing'] == '1' ){
    $display= "display: table-row;";
  }else{
    $display= "display:none !important";
  }
  ?>
 <tr id="subShow" style="<?php echo $display; ?>">
    <td><span class="style2"> New Box: </span></td>
    <td><input class="inputfield"  typ="text" name="subject" id="subject" size="25" value="<?php echo @$adddetails['Newbox'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: please create a working fiddle with your code and paste the link in your question. for that question just the created html and js is needed.

Comment: Please don't suppress errors using `@`. That's a major anti pattern since you're hiding errors, making it _really_ hard to debug your code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sure, Will follow it

Comment: Please change the following things in your script:
1. The function name is wrong 'onchange="return subChange();"'
Change to 'onchange="subjectChange();"'
Note: You do not need return unless you handle the response data.
2. Instead of getting the text value of select option, use val().
var value = $('#testing option:selected').val();